# Is there a pow method in bigInt package in Go

Tags: go

I am looking at the [documentation of a big integer arithmetic](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) in Go and trying to find a method suitable for calculation of a^n (something like `pow(a, n)` in python).

To my surprise among some straightforward functions like [GCD](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.GCD), [Binomial](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Binomial) and not really straightforward as [modinverse](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.ModInverse) I can not find pow. Am I missing it or should I write my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func (z *Int) Exp(x, y, m *Int) *Int
```

> Exp sets z = x^y mod |m| (i.e. the sign of m is ignored), and returns z. If y <= 0, the result is 1 mod |m|; if m == nil or m == 0, z = x^y. See Knuth, volume 2, section 4.6.3.

Comment: thank you. They selected really strange name for it. At least for me it associates with `e^x`. And during this time I almost finished my implementation.

Comment: just found out that I can not use this function without `m` provided. So it looks like it is not the one I needed.

Comment: @SalvadorDali, that seems counter to the documentation "if m == nil or m == 0, z = x^y"; what's special about your usage that that doesn't work?

Comment: @DaveC in mathematics `a%0` is undefined, so I would never even think about putting `m=0`. If it would work, it would surprise me and I would find it shockingly counterintuitive (I would expect to see some sort of error). As for `m=nil`, I did not know this before yesterday. I kindly asked Daniel a couple of days ago what should I do in this case, have not seen a reply and unaccepted my accept vote. I would be happy to grant it again if you/him/anyone would edit the question with this information

Answer (score 1):

Because I almost finished my own implementation (Daniel's recommendation does not work, because you always have to provide a modulo there) I am adding it here in case someone would like to see how it might be [implemented efficiently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Here is [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NBZsvGtK0i) and my function:

```
func powBig(a, n int) *big.Int{
    tmp := big.NewInt(int64(a))
    res := big.NewInt(1)
    for n > 0 {
        temp := new(big.Int)
        if n % 2 == 1 {
            temp.Mul(res, tmp)
            res = temp
        }
        temp = new(big.Int)
        temp.Mul(tmp, tmp)
        tmp = temp
        n /= 2
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: For all values I tested with (your version doesn't work with n<0 and takes too long for large n) the naive (reallocates too much) version of `new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(int64(a)), big.NewInt(int64(n)), nil)` produced the *exact* same values (verified with [`testing/quick`](https://play.golang.org/p/1Z01aZ31oB)), but did so faster.

Comment: @DaveC why would my answer work with n < 0? Remembering just a small fraction of math, one would see that with n < 0 the result would not be big integer. It would be a small real, so if I would like to calculate it, I can use just pow method in math. Also before you made another downvote I will confess that it also would not work with n=3.14. Have I ever told that my own function that I wrote in 10 minutes would work faster than highly tested and tuned version from the library (PS. seeing that you told that it would take too long: what value of n would end up with my function being 2 slower)?